# Fait-on la liaison devant le mot « avec » ?

Tags: liaisons

Dans des situations telles que

> Chacun prit part avec joie...

ou bien

> Il voit avec plaisir...

faut-il placer une liaison devant le mot "avec" ? Est-ce qu'il existe des exceptions pour ce mot en particulier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il n'y a rien de particulier en ce qui concerne le mot « avec »; prenons le mot « à » et le même problème se pose; par exemple dans « Il a pris part à une fête religieuse. » la liaison ne se fait pas non plus avec la dernière lettre de « part » mais elle se fait avec la lettre « r » (…pris para une…). Lorsque les liaisons sont faites dans ces cas-là (avec le t au lieu du r) on les appelle des liaisons mal à propos. Il n'existe pas de règle unique mais tout un ensemble de [règles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais) pour les liaisons; il existe trois types de liaisons : les liaisons obligatoires, les liaisons facultatives, et les liaisons interdites ou en d'autres termes mal à propos.  Pour une personne étrangère qui apprend le français un dictionnaire qui traite des liaisons  est nécessaire si elle est soucieuse de les respecter scrupuleusement. Pour les indigènes les liaisons correctes s'apprenne en parlant et en écoutant. Un étudiant étranger peut donc aussi apprendre les liaisons au moyen de matériel audio et/ou en participant à des discussion en français. Le problème des liaisons est un véritable problème de la langue française et il faut savoir que même les français parfois ne savent pas s'il convient ou non de faire une liaison.

Dans « Il voit avec plaisir. » la liaison est interdite.

Comment: Si je comprends bien, les liaisons mal à propos sont donc des liaisons interdites?

Comment: @SolidWaterIsIce Oui, à moins que je fasse erreur; c'est du savoir par ouï-dire que je tiens de ma mère. Il y a une précision à apporter à ma réponse : la liaison est dite « interdite » pour la seconde phrase; c'est plutôt dire que je ne me rappelle pas d'un seul cas de l'avoir entendue. Comme vous pouvez constater dans la réponse de aCOSwt cette liaison serait facultative et donc à la rigueur faisable; je ne pourrais pas dire qu'elle soit vraiment déplaisante.

Answer (score 2):

Une liaison n'est que très rarement considérée **obligatoire**.
Elle est bien plus souvent **facultative** ou **interdite**.

Ne pas en faire donc est souvent... prudent.

On considérerait :

- La liaison **facultative** entre le verbe et son complément comme dans *Il voit avec plaisir*

Attention tout de même... dans certains cas, certains milieux... adopter une règle facultative est rapidement assimilé à de l'affectation.

Dans cet exemple précis, **je** ne fais pas la liaison.

- La liaison **interdite** entre un mot au singulier se terminant par une consonne muette ou deux consonnes dont une seule est sonore, ce qui est le cas de *pa**rt*** d'où : 
  *chacun prend part... avec joie...* Avec joie certes... mais... sans liaison :-)

**EDIT :** Suite à une observation juste de Montée de lait en commentaires :

*Vit* se termine par une brêve et *avec* commence par une brêve.
Dans cette circonstance, un narrateur appliqué va devoir soit marquer une pause entre les deux soit ajouter un truc entre les deux.
On observe qu'il préfère souvent (quand c'est possible) la seconde solution au temps mort. La possibilité d'une liaison offrant cette opportunité, on dira alors avec Homère et Montée de lait : *il vi-t-avec* sans qu'il soit effectivement question d'affectation. Il s'agit juste d'élocution.

Cette justification ne vaut évidemment pas pour *voit* qui se termine par une diphtongue c'est donc encore à dire une longue.

Comment: Je ne la fais pas non plus en discussion. Si je narre une histoire, cependant, je la fais (pensons par exemple au plus probant passé simple, peu utilisé en conversation, mais omniprésent dans les contes et récits: il vit t’avec joie qu’Hermione était saine et sauve). Tout est affaire de circonstances dans la liaison facultative: affectation parfois certes, élégance désirable en d’autres cas. Un peu comme le passé simple, d'ailleurs.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Héhé! Oui absolument. On peut raconter Harry Potter comme Homère l'aurait sans doute fait sans qu'il soit pour autant question d'affectation. EDIT apporté dans ma réponse.